# what is difference among different veryion of Shared Libraries?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, shared-libraries

I am using Ubuntu and have installed Boost Library. In my

> /usr/lib/

directory I have 3 versions of shared libraries;

```
libboost_filesystem-mt.so 
libboost_filesystem.so
libboost_filesystem.so.1.68.0
```

what is difference among each other ?

Comment: See __6.1 Library Naming__: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

Comment: I suspect at least one (maybe 2?) of these is a symlink to another